# Javascript - Use multiple variables for object property

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, object

object.js

```js
var a = "level_2";
var b = "level_3";
var c;

const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const num_1 = nums[Math.floor(Math.random() * nums.length)];
const num_2 = nums[Math.floor(Math.random() * nums.length)];

console.log({ num_1, num_2 });

if (num_1 <= num_2) {
  c = [a];
} else {
  c = [a][b];
}

/**
 * Lets say I make a database call, the result is from a promise I use '.then()'
 * eg:
 * ...
 * .then(level_1 => {
 *      let final;
 *      final = level_1[c]
 *      res.statusCode(200).json({ final })
 * })...
 *
 * This is what I'm trying to achieve where I can determine the object property
 * how deep in the object I would like to go before I get the object.*/

const level_1 = {
  level_2: {
    level_3: "level_3",
    level_4: "level_4",
    level_5: {
      level_6: "level_6",
    },
  },
};

console.log("\nPrint 1:\n", level_1[a]);
console.log("\nPrint 2:\n", level_1[a][b]);
console.log("\nPrint 3:\n", level_1[c]);
```

The if statement shows the randomness I'll be dealing with when it comes to which information I need from the object.

Result 1:
This does not work when `c` is `[a][b]`

```
$ node object.js
{ num_1: 4, num_2: 1 }

Print 1:
 {
  level_3: 'level_3',
  level_4: 'level_4',
  level_5: { level_6: 'level_6' }
}

Print 2:
 level_3

Print 3:
 undefined
```

Result 2:
This works well when `c` if only `[a]`

```
$ node object.js
{ num_1: 2, num_2: 3 }

Print 1:
 {
  level_3: 'level_3',
  level_4: 'level_4',
  level_5: { level_6: 'level_6' }
}

Print 2:
 level_3

Print 3:
 {
  level_3: 'level_3',
  level_4: 'level_4',
  level_5: { level_6: 'level_6' }
}
```

How do I get `c` to work? As you can see `Result 1` returns undefined for `c` This has been puzzling me for a while now and it would make my code very efficient if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to combine properties, either use an array of properties, or join all properties by `.`. Then, to retrieve the nested value, use one of the methods at [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arays-by-string-path):

```js
const level_1 = {
  level_2: {
    level_3: "level_3",
    level_4: "level_4",
    level_5: {
      level_6: "level_6",
    },
  },
};

var a = "level_2";
var b = "level_3";

const c = [a, b];
const getNested = (obj, props) => props.reduce((a, prop) => a[prop], obj);

console.log(level_1[a]);
console.log(level_1[a][b]);
console.log(getNested(level_1, c));
```

Comment: This was VERY helpful, I noted this. I have edited my question please have a look. Your answer was exactly what i was looking for.